# Powershell - Register-ObjectEvent mstsc issue - Event not fired at the right time

Tags: powershell, events, start-process

I am currently writing a powershell (5.0) script to run and manage the ending of RDP sessions on Windows thin clients.

Once the RDP session ended, the script runs a specific function. To do so, mstsc is run as a process (with the [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-5.0) cmdlet).Then [Register-ObjectEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent?view=powershell-5.0)  is used to register and catch the *Exited* event of the mstsc process.

When mstsc is run without the -ArgumentList parameter (as shown in the example below), everything works fine. The Exited event is fired as soon as the RDP session ends or when the RDP login dialog gets closed before login.

```
$rdpSession = Start-Process -FilePath mstsc -PassThru
$RegisteredEvent = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $rdpSession -EventName Exited -Action {rdpSessionEnd} -Verbose
```

Using the -ArgumentList parameter to provide a custom rdp file path (as shown in the example below) makes the *Exited* event fired just after the mstsc process start, not waiting for the rdp session to end.

```
$rdpSession = Start-Process -FilePath mstsc -ArgumentList C:\RDS\RDS.rdp -PassThru 
$RegisteredEvent = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $rdpSession -EventName Exited -Action {rdpSessionEnd}
```

The script is to be run on 64 bits Windows. I previously read things about the need to run the system32 or SysWOW64 folder mstsc version depending on the OS is a 32 or 64 bits version. Using both of the instances of mstsc.exe with their full path did not solve the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Can you confirm that problem in the event: that `mstsc`, which you start, is still running and not start some child process and exit itself?

Answer (score 0):

PetSerAl, you put me back on the track I should have explored a little further as it is the right one !

Indeed, the first mstsc process starts a child mstsc process then exits itself.

Proceeding this way did the job (see shortened and unoptimized code below as an example) :

1. Running the "parent" mstsc process using the rdp file parameter.
2. Registering the "exited" event of the "parent" process so that, when
   raised,  a statement register the "exited" event of the "child"
   mstsc process to run the specific function (assuming the "child"
   process has been created before the parent process exits itself and
   that the child process is the only remaining "mstsc" named running
   process).
3. Ending or aborting the rdp session raises the child mstsc
   process "exited" and the runs the registered function.

   ```
   function registerRdpSessionExitedEvent {
       # Registering the "exited" event of the child process (the rdp session itself) to run the <rdpSessionEnd> function when raised

       $rdpSession = Get-Process -Name mstsc
       $rdpSessionExitedEvent  = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $rdpSession -EventName Exited -Action {rdpSessionEnd}
   }

   function rdpSessionEnd {
       # To be run when the rdp session has ended or has been aborted by user
       <Some statements...>
   }


    #1. Starting the parent mstsc process using the rdp file parameter.
    $mstscLauncher = Start-Process -FilePath mstsc -ArgumentList C:\RDS\RDS.rdp -PassThru 

   #2. Registering the "exited" event of the "parent" process to run the <registerRdpSessionExitedEvent> function when raised
   $mstscLauncherExitedEvent =  Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $mstscLauncher -EventName Exited -Action {registerRdpSessionExitedEvent}
   ```

Thanks a lot !